# null when use double server-side actions

Tags: lightning, action

```
 let action = component.get("c.actionOne");

    action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
        let state = response.getState();
        if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
            let respOne = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());  
            console.log(respOne);

            let action2 = component.get("c.actionTwo");
            action2.setParams({ "stringParam": JSON.stringify(respOne)});

            action2.setCallback(this, function (response) {
                let state = response.getState();
                console.log(state);
                if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                    console.log(response.getReturnValue());
                    }
                } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                    console.log('Failed with below state: ' + state);
                    let errors = response.getError();
                    if (errors) {
                        if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                            console.log("Error " + errors[0].message);
                        } else {
                            console.log("Unknown Error");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            $A.enqueueAction(action2);

        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
            console.log('Failed with below state: ' + state);
            let errors = response.getError();
            if (errors) {
                if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                    console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown Error");
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

When I use this controller, in console I get right info from "actionOne" but when I try insert this to second action I get null in "actionTwo"

```
@AuraEnabled public static String actionOne(){ 
    return 'response One';
}

@AuraEnabled public static String actionTwo(String stringParam){ 
    // here responseOne is null
    system.debug('stringParam= ' + stringParam);
    return stringParam;
}
```

Comment: That's because you're not setting the correct parameter. You're setting 'stringParam' instead of 'responseOne' like it is named in the Apex method

Comment: My mistake, already fix in question but its not help

Comment: Can you try removing the quotes around the stringParam in the component controller? See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm Sometimes, I found, the caching can play a role here when changing parameter names. Could you try to refresh the cache and see if that helps, just in case? For me shift+f5 (twice, don't ask me why) usually solves a lot of problems.

Comment: I removed, after I try `action2.setParams({ "stringParam": 'test'});  action2.setParams({ "stringParam": "test"}); action2.setParams({ stringParam: 'test'});  action2.setParams({ stringParam: "test"});` the same problem

Comment: Error message: An internal server error has occurred
Error ID: 2060152508-73903 (119852647)

Comment: If you're getting an Internal Server Error, you need to contact support.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I received Internal error with gack id `119852647` in three different cases:
1. System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null. 
2. System.QueryException: Limit expression must be of type Integer
3. Index out of bound runtime exception

When I tried to reproduce your issue and take your code

```
<aura:component controller="tcc" >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

</aura:component>
```

javascript controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        let action = component.get("c.actionOne");

        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            let state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                let respOne = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());  
                console.log(respOne);

                let action2 = component.get("c.actionTwo");
                action2.setParams({ "stringParam": JSON.stringify(respOne)});

                action2.setCallback(this, function (response) {
                    let state = response.getState();
                    console.log(state);
                    if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                        console.log(response.getReturnValue());
                    } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                        console.log('Failed with below state: ' + state);
                        let errors = response.getError();
                        if (errors) {
                            if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                                console.log("Error " + errors[0].message);
                            } else {
                                console.log("Unknown Error");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                $A.enqueueAction(action2);

            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                console.log('Failed with below state: ' + state);
                let errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Unknown Error");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

my controller

```
public class tcc {
@AuraEnabled public static String actionOne(){ 
    return 'response One';
}

@AuraEnabled public static String actionTwo(String stringParam){ 
    // here responseOne is null
    system.debug('stringParam= ' + stringParam);
    return stringParam;
}
}
```

I receive error

> This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Error in
>   $A.getCallback() [Unexpected token r in JSON at position 0] Callback
>   failed: apex://tcc/ACTION$actionOne Failing descriptor: {c:testcomp}

because you are trying to deserialize string. Instead you just should remove `JSON.parse`.

When I removed both `JSON.parse` and `JSON.deserialize` everything worked fine

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        let action = component.get("c.actionOne");

        action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            let state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                let respOne = response.getReturnValue();  
                console.log(respOne);

                let action2 = component.get("c.actionTwo");
                action2.setParams({ "stringParam": respOne});

                action2.setCallback(this, function (response) {
                    let state = response.getState();
                    console.log(state);
                    if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                        console.log(response.getReturnValue());
                    } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                        console.log('Failed with below state: ' + state);
                        let errors = response.getError();
                        if (errors) {
                            if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                                console.log("Error " + errors[0].message);
                            } else {
                                console.log("Unknown Error");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                $A.enqueueAction(action2);

            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                console.log('Failed with below state: ' + state);
                let errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
                    } else {
                        console.log("Unknown Error");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

and I see the following logs

> response One
>
> SUCCESS
>
> response One

Comment: I wrote than even when I send hardcode strink it's didn't work.

Comment: I fix problem. The problem was that my internal action - method was name "saveSettings". When I change name it's start working fine.